# In ggplot. How to have axis title containing symbol such as %.

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a boxplot in ggplot2. When the plot is made the y axis should read "Straw.P.uptake.%", but instead of % there are two full stops. I have tried adding check.names to remove the full stops from the header names but ggplot doesn't read the names at all when I do that.

My code which works to make the plot:

```
Fost13 <- read.csv("UPTAKE_13.csv", header = TRUE)`

Box_18<-ggplot(Fost13, aes(x=Amendment, y=Straw.P.uptake, 
fill=Added.straw.amendment)) +
geom_boxplot()+ theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
Box_18 + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Green3", "White", "Yellow3"))`
```

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: Just add `+xlab("Straw.P.uptake.%")`. R variable (and column) names should not contain percent symbols.

Comment: But on the off chance they do, you can still reference them using "backticks": ``aes(x=Amendment, y=`Straw P uptake %`)`` (where I'm assuming your other periods are spaces in the original column name)

Comment: Hi MrFlick, thanks so much that worked. Thanks Artem Sokolov, it sort of worked but changed the boxes for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `ylab` argument to ggplot. For example:

```
bla <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(2,3,4,5))
ggplot(bla, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + ylab("hello%")
```